# Why am I getting error 405 in my ajax petition?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5.7

I've been trying to solve this problem for quite a while now. I am trying to make a post petition using the XMLHttpRequest, however it keeps throwing state 405. I'd like some insight on what's making this happen, at first I thought it had something to do with the headers, but then I added them and the issue persisted.

Here's my code

```
const searchBar = document.querySelector('#search');
const resultList = document.querySelector('#result_list');
const browser = new XMLHttpRequest();
searchBar.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.which == 27 || event.which == 9) { 
        resultList.hidden = true; 
    }
    else {
        resultList.hidden = false; 
        let request = {
            'value': searchBar.value
        }
        browser.open('POST', 'browse');
        console.log('Esto es lo que traemos', request);
        browser.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')['content']);
        browser.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        browser.withCredentials = true;
        browser.send(request);
        browser.onreadystatechange = print_s;
    }   
});
function print_s(a) {
    console.log('Test' , a);
}
```

this is my controller

```
    public function browseItems(Request $request) {
        return json_encode($request);
    }
```

And this is how I mapped it in my web.php

```
Route::post('/browse', 'ItemController@browseItems');
```

and here's what i get in my network tab

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING at us?

Comment: Your server doesn't allow requests using post method.

Comment: Can you bring up the Network tab of your developer console and see what the full response is?

Comment: Are you hitting the correct url?? There may also be a chance that you have defined the route twice

Comment: You're trying to access `/Compras_TC/items/browse`. Unless your route is in a prefixed group, it's most likely either `/browse` or `/Compras_TC/browse`. You can check `php artisan routes:list` in your command line to see what the exact route should be.